# Adding a formula into a cell via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macrco that opens a workbook and inserts formulas in one sheet to link it to another worksheet in the same workbook. My issue as the macro is running an 'Open Dialogue' pops up asking me for a location of a worksheet. Hitting cancels has no adverse effect on the flow of the macro and the formula is insertted properly. Any reason for excel showing that dialogue? I am linking a cell to another cell in the same workbook.

```
xlWB.Worksheets("Cover Sheet").Range("H42") = "=" & Second_Sheet & "!" & "A1"
```

Comment: Does the sheet name held by `Second_Sheet` have any spaces in it?  If so, change to `"='" & Second_Sheet & "'!" & "A1"`  (you can do this safely anyway)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are short-cutting a number of potential error circumstances.

```
xlWB.Worksheets("Cover Sheet").Range("H42") = "=" & xlWB.worksheets(Second_Sheet).cells(1, "A").address(0, 0, external:=true)
```

That should unequivocally define your cell reference. However, application.inputbox has an option to only accept cell references (`type:=8`) and that may be the better option in a larger scope.

Comment: since OP's wrote _"another worksheet in the same workbook"_, I'd qualify `worksheets(Second_Sheet)` with `xlWB` workbook reference, too (possibly enclosing the whole line in a ` With xlWb ... End With` block. And since she didn't specify if `Second_Sheet` is a `Worksheet` reference or a `String`, you could treat both cases. Finally, watch that "arger scope"...

Comment: Good catch! Especially so with external:=true.

Comment: I will try this out. Second_Sheet is a string with the name of the sheet. I was building a string that is equivalent to the formula if you were linking two cells manually within a  workbook. Regards, Mahmoud.